# Таблица с большим количеством строк

Tags: highload, mysql

Интересует такой момент.

Как работают таблицы с более > **`10 000 000 000`** строк?

Допустим, у меня есть мощный сервер + **MySQL**. Ну PHP там и прочее..

- Как разбиваются таблицы?
- Как
     добавляются новые поля в разбитые
     таблицы?
- Как производится быстрая
     выборка из этих таблиц?

---

Допустим, у меня есть модуль пользователей - две таблицы: **`users`** и **`users_fields`**.

В таблице **`users_fields`** хранится информация пользователя (о себе, статус, номер телефона, ссылки на страницу в соц. сетях и прочее). То есть, вся не системная информация.

Эта таблица сделана для того, чтобы можно было легко добавлять новые поля.

Каждая строка в таблице это информация какого либо поля пользователя.

```
uid | field | value

1   | status | тест
1   |   vk   | id1
2   | status | 
2   |   vk   | id2
```

Допустим, у меня есть **100** полей. При регистрации автоматически в таблице полей создаются пустые поля.

Проблема в том, что если у меня зарегистрируются **`100 000 000`** пользователей, то количество строк в таблице с информацией полей будет **`1 000 000 000`**.

**Как быть в такой ситуации?**

Comment: стоит смотреть на nosql

Comment: @Gorets Почему сразу NoSQL? Не факт, что по ресурсам будет "дешевле". Кроме того, может возникнуть необходимость в ACID-транзакциях, чем тоже не могут похвастаться многие БД класса NoSQL. Надо конкретно на задачу смотреть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужен шардинг - сегментация БД по некоторым признакам. Самое сложное здесь, определиться с тем, как именно делить данные, т.к. методика сильно зависит от того, насколько данные зависимы друг от друга.

В качестве простого и показательного примера можно разбить всех пользователей по диапазонам ников. Для простоты будем учитывать только первую букву ника и считать, что все ники записаны в нижнем регистре с использованием только лишь латиницы.

Далее прикидываем каково распределение пользователей по первым буквам ников. В простейшем случае на каждую букву выделяем свой сервер. Это конечно же расточительно. Поэтому группируем пользователей по первым буквам таким образом, чтобы в каждом диапозоне оказалось примерно одинаковое кол-во пользователей (т.е. чтобы распределение было примерно равномерным).

Теперь при чтении/записи мы всегда знаем, на какой сервер нам нужно пойти с запросом, при условии, что у нас есть первая буква ника.

Понятно, что такая схема разделения данных не бесплатна. Распределение данных по шардам может измениться. В таком случае нужно перераспределять данные.

Comment: У меня нет ников. Но я думаю id подойдут?

Comment: @exec Да, конечно. По некоторой хешфункции от id вполне можно шардировать. Правда если предполагается использовать запрос по связанным пользователям, то нужно, чтобы они либо оказалисть на одном сервере, либо была возможность запросить эти данные со всех серверов.