# Обработка большого количества данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, товарищи! Возникла следующая проблема: имеется две таблицы с большим количеством аналитических данных. В одной таблице 5млн строк, в другой - 165млн. Если схематично, то таблицы выглядят так:

```
id   - int, AutoIncrement
int0 - int
int1 - int
int2 - int
data - int
```

Из таблиц нужно сделать выборку таким образом, чтобы были показаны только те результаты, значение поля data у которых встречается в таблице не менее N раз. Для примера возьмём N = 5. Вот такой запрос я написал:

```
select * from results r where (select count(*) from results where data = r.data group by data limit 1) >= 5 order by data;
```

Проверил запрос на маленькой табличке в 10 строк - работает. Но всю печаль ситуации я понял сейчас, ибо этот запрос на таблице в 5млн строк я запустил ровно 4 часа назад... Запрос до сих пор обрабатывается. Боюсь представить, что будет с таблицей в 165млн строк хД Видимо, я написал нечто ужасное и надо было все это дело реализовать как-то иначе. Прошу указать мне мои ошибки/предложить идеи для оптимизации

Comment: Всего-то в записи пять полей по 8 байт, итого 40 байт, да 165M записей. На компе с 16G это все просто в оперативку загрузить можно.

Comment: Посмотрите план выполнения для начала. У вас есть индекс по data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Коррелированный запрос на таком объёме данных, да ещё если версия сервера не самая распоследняя - это безнадёжно.

Простейший способ оптимизации - получение в подзапросе списка data, которые требуется вывести:

```
SELECT *
FROM results 
WHERE data IN ( SELECT data
                FROM results 
                GROUP BY data
                HAVING COUNT(*)>=5
              );
```

Ещё более разумное решение - предрасчёт данных, получаемых подзапросом, в дополнительной (или временной - но тогда её придётся строить для каждого экземпляра запроса) таблице. Т.е.

```
CREATE TABLE data_count (data int, cnt bigint);
CREATE INDEX count_data ON data_count (cnt, data);
INSERT INTO data_count (data, cnt)
    SELECT data, COUNT(*)
    FROM results 
    GROUP BY data;
```

И соответственно быстрая выборка

```
SELECT results.*
FROM results, data_count
WHERE results.data = data_count.data
  AND data_count.cnt >= 5;
```

Актуализация таблицы в зависимости от требуемой точности конечного результата выполняется либо периодически, либо набором триггеров на основной таблице данных.

Во всех случаях предполагается, что в исходной таблице имеется индекс с префиксным полем data.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: в insert запросе не хватает `count` ?

Comment: @teran Да, спасибо! Добавляю... готово.

Comment: Быстрая выборка с использованием `results.*` - нуну.

Comment: @Akina разрешите поздравить вас с достижением 10.000!

Comment: @And А какие сложности? Автору нужны данные из не входящих в индекс полей - по-любому это выборка по индексу из таблицы. А тут что одно поле тянуть, что все - невелика разница.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Благодарствую.

Answer (score 0):

Заодно проверьте настройки [mysql](http://phpprofi.ru/blogs/post/76), [шардинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/190289/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA), если возможно делайте предварительную выборку чтобы уменьшить количество строк для последующего поиска, можете добавить поля в мелкую таблицу которые будет отвечать за количество записей в большой таблице, а также хранить строковой массив с их индексами и обновляйте их при добавлении новых записей. [Стандартные советы](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=692).